# How do I assign a value in an if statement inside a function definition?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, assign

I'm very new to R and asking questions on StackOverflow, so I apologize in advance if something is unclear or I'm asking a silly question.

I am trying to define a function. When executing the function, a variable (`prize`) should be created with a specific value (3), iff a different variable (`symbols`) contains only one unique value. I'm doing it this way because I'm following the exercises in "Hands on Programming with R", by Garret Grolemund. (chapter 7).

Assigning values to `symbols` is fine and my if statement returns the correct value for `prize` when I take it out of the `function()` definition.

```
symbols <- c("DD", "DD", "DD")

if (all(symbols == symbols[1])) {
     prize <- 3
   }

prize 
[3]
```

The problem appears when I put the if statement into a `function()` definition, like so:

```
symbols <- c("DD", "DD", "DD")

prize <- 100

score <- function() {
 if (all(symbols == symbols[1])) {
     prize <- 3
   }
 }

score()
prize
[100]
```

If I call `prize` after `score()` I just get the value that I manually assigned `prize` before running the function `score()` : 100.

I realize that I'm programming the function `score()` without any arguments (in `function( arg)`. But if I'm not mistaken this shouldn't be a problem?

Thanks for your response.

EDIT: After some further testing I seems that it's because any variables created in a function are only there in the function itself, and not in the global environment? Is that correct?

Comment: R is a functional language. One of the core ideas of a functional language is that when you run a function, it should not modify your global environment. Functions should return new values, not change a global state. Basically this type of behavior is discouraged, though it is technically possible with the `<<-` assignment operator rather than `<-`. But it would be better for your function to return a value that you can then assign to a variable if you want

Comment: Hey, thanks that explains it!

Comment: as @MrFlick said it is bad practise to let your function influence your global environment (it will get messy). But if you want to see the result of a variable that is defined inside your function you could use ```return(prize)``` 1 line above the last parenthesis of your function